# OpenCV waitKey() should return -1 but didn't

Tags: c++, opencv

In the [doc](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html#waitkey) it says that

> It returns the code of the pressed key or -1 if no key was pressed before the specified time had elapsed.

But it returns 255 instead of -1 when no key is pressed on my **Ubuntu 14.04** device. Why is that?

Code example:

```
#include <opencv/cv.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;

int main(void) {
    Mat image = Mat::zeros(100, 100, CV_8UC3);
    char window_name[] = "waitKey() example";
    imshow(window_name, image);

    const int DELAY = 50;
    int c = waitKey(DELAY);
    std::cout << c << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: post your code, please!

Comment: The return type is `int`. If you're reading it as `uchar` it'll be 255 instead of -1

Comment: Code is simply imshow() and waitKey()

Comment: @Miki No, I read it as int.

Comment: This works as expected for me

Comment: @Miki I am working on Ubuntu 14.04, what is yours?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

recently some code modification has made on `cv::waitKey()` and there is a [fix](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/pull/7935) about this issue not merged yet.